# Is this a good format for a Python program with 2 frames on one window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need a window that contains 2 frames in one window for formatting purposes. I am new to object oriented programming. I came up with this (it took a bit of time to get it working, lots of research). Is this a proper use of the class structures? Should the left and right classes inherit the main class instead of tk.Frame?

```
import tkinter as tk

class main(tk.Tk):

  def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    self.title("Frames Test")
    # self.resizable(width = False, height = False)

    self.left = left(self)
    self.right = right(self)


class left(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent):
    self.frame = tk.Frame(parent, height = 2, border = 10, relief = tk.RAISED)
    self.frame.pack(fill = tk.X, padx = 5, pady = 5, side = tk.LEFT, expand=True)

    tk.Label(self.frame, text="left").pack()


class right(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent):
    self.frame = tk.Frame(parent, height = 2, border = 10, relief = tk.GROOVE)
    self.frame.pack(fill = tk.X, padx = 5, pady = 5, side = tk.LEFT, expand=True)

    tk.Label(self.frame, text="right is larger").pack()
    tk.Label(self.frame, text="right is larger").pack()


main = main()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to make one class with two class instances (left and right). And set the window sizes etc as instance variables.

Comment: I don't understand how I would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a good format for a Python program with 2 frames on one window?

Yes, and no.

**Yes**, in that it's very good to create separate classes for different sections of your UI. **No**, in that you've implemented it wrong. So, correct architecture but incorrect implementation.

Consider this code:

```
class left(tk.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent):
    self.frame = tk.Frame(parent, height = 2, border = 10, relief = tk.RAISED)
    self.frame.pack(fill = tk.X, padx = 5, pady = 5, side = tk.LEFT, expand=True)

    tk.Label(self.frame, text="left").pack()
```

For one, you're not adhering to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standards. More importantly:

- `left` *is a* frame because you inherit from `tk.Frame`
- you do not properly call the `__init__` of the superclass (`tk.Frame`)
- you create *another* frame inside of `left` which as far as I can tell serves no purpose (well, no purpose that can't be equally served by the class itself)

In other words, there's no reason to create `self.frame` because `self` itself is a frame.

Another problem is that you're letting `left` and `right` pack itself into its parent. You should not do this. The code that creates `left` and `right` should be responsible for calling `pack` or `grid`.

Here is an example that fixes those problems:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Frames Test")

        self.left = Left(self)
        self.right = Right(self)

        self.left.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
        self.right.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)

class Left(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Left, self).__init__(parent, height=2, border=10, relief=tk.RAISED)

        tk.Label(self, text="left").pack()


class Right(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Right, self).__init__(parent, height=2, border=10, relief=tk.RAISED)

        tk.Label(self, text="right is larger").pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="right is larger").pack()


main = Main()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: That makes sense to me. Classes and their inheritances are still somewhat confusing. I will have to look at PEP8. I found that with python 3.7 I could use super() just as well.